# Is Androids new Jack compiler really that slow?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jack-and-jill

On some of my Android projects I see that building got quite slow since using the new Jack compiler. I need it to use Java 8 features like lambdas.

But the long building time is a bit disturbing. So I set up a new Android project. It contains just a `MainActivity` with one button which reacts on your click.

```
package de.xappo.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There is nothing else except from the layout file which just contains a a `TextView` and a `Button` within a `RelativeLayout`.

[image: Profiling gradle buidling]

As you can see in the picture all the jack gradle tasks together take about 75 seconds. Is this normal? This hole example app builds in less than 22 seconds without jack. So is this big difference normal?

I already managed Java heap size within my `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Is there still any thing to do to improve jack compiling performance? Or do you know about any updates planned on jack to improve building time?

Comment: it prolly because CA is using clear build ...

Comment: I have noticed that the Jack tool chain really struggles with dependencies like Google services and Firebase.

Comment: Also InstantRun doesn't work with Jack, for now, that also might have a huge impact in build/run performance.

Comment: @Selvin What do you mean by CA?

Comment: it was typo i meant CI(Continuous integration)

Comment: @Selvin OK but all what I show here is run locally. And yes, I am using clean and build when having such values. Can I improve that somehow? Due to several repeated errors I have to clean ofter.

Comment: i second this question, it is definitely so slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html), the Jack toolchain on Android is deprecated and java8 support will be directly integrated into Android's standard `javac` and `dx` toolchain. I switched to Jack for java8 support, but then transitioned to [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) because Jack was so slow.

Comment: Yes, me too. But it was because Proguard didn't obfuscate my code when I was using Jack.